# JavaScript function not firing in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I created a textbox and wrote `onfocus="getFocus()" //"getFocus();"` also not working.

Now I wrote function in JavaScript:

```
  function getFocus()

    {
        alert('Hello I Got Focus !!');
    }
```

The problem is in IE8 it worked perfectly, but in IE9 alert is not showing. Can anyone tell what is wrong with the following code?

I also tried:

```
txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","getFocus()")

txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","getFocus();") //also not working
```

but still it didn't worked

I too tried:

```
txtAmt.Attributes.Add("onfocus","javascript:getFocus();")
```

In Internet option ActiveScripting is also 'Enabled'
Now I am worried; what to do?

Comment: Please reproduce this problem in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), then we can see what's happening. Or what's not happening.

Comment: What is "textbox"? <input type="text" /> or <textarea> or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure if java script is enabled in your browser .Enable it or rest 
Go to tools -> internet options -> advanced -> reset and it'll go back to default after restart. Also restore advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TTxdK/ - tested in IE9 on Windows Vista, onfocus works